# Can't input numbers, because I get characters instead

Tags: ultravnc

We use UltraVNC for remote-accessing other XP PC's on our company’s internal network.

We have a problem where frequently if an internal user uses UltraVNC to connect to another internal  PC, when he types in a number, he gets the associated character instead.  For example if he types a `1`, he gets `!` instead and if he types `2`, he gets `@`.

Why does this occur and what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is stuck somewhere--the easiest way to verify is to see if the keyboard behaves normally when you hold down your <kbd>Shift</kbd> while connected remotely.

One way to solve this on Windows is to use [StickyKeys](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-xp/help/using-stickykeys) on the remote computer to "stick" the remote <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (which will result in the desired behavior: <kbd>1</kbd> will input the number 1, etc.).

Comment: the shift keys, are not the problem. this problem has been going on for a long time on multiple PC's and is not manifested when I use logmein. it just manifests when I use UVNC. Please advise

Comment: If that's not the fix then I'm out of ideas--good luck with the problem! Have you tried posting to the UltraVNC mailing list or hopping on IRC? If you solve the problem there, please self-answer this question with the solution you found so other people can benefit from it as well.

Comment: I truly appreciate your advice